# Custom label and values in select list in Spring MVC

Tags: select, spring-mvc, label

I have a user drop down in my JSP page where I show the user list. In the drop down I need to show the user name and email as the label while value will be user id and user email address. So I need to concatenate the properties of my user instance to show the proper label and values.

What is the best possible approach to do this in the Spring MVC?

I can iterate over the list in my Spring Controller and concatenate the properties and then create a new list which will be displayed in the page. This is the way I can think of.

Any better ideas?

Comment: add some code as to how you are planning to do it as it would then help to update or provide some appropriate suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add users list object to the model and use standard tag lib to build the html

```
<select id="users" name="users">
  <c:forEach items="users" var="user">
    <option value="${user.id}">${user.name} [${user.email}]</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```